# receive commands uing Bluetoothsocket connection

Tags: java, android, android-bluetooth

I am trying to open a connection with my laptop which has bluetooth from my phone. Server program is running in my laptop. My intention was to establish a connection with my laptop to send some inputs continuously on the same created socket. Connection was successfully established and a byte was sent to the server running in my laptop but after pressing send button nothing was sent.

The below code works fine for the first attempt. When i am trying to resend using the same connection byte value was not sent. When i launching my application for second time my phone gets hanged. I am looking for memory issues but i couldn't find any memory issues. Did i miss something ? Do i need to do something.

```
public class BluetoothActivity extends Activity {
        private TextView myLabel;
        private EditText myTextbox;
        private BluetoothAdapter mBluetoothAdapter;
        private BluetoothSocket mmSocket;
        private BluetoothDevice mmDevice;
        private OutputStream mmOutputStream;
        private BufferedOutputStream mbuffStream;
        private ProgressDialog progressBar;
        private int progressBarStatus;
        private Context mContext;
        private TextView devicesLabel;
        private TextView devices;

        private final static int MAX_VALUE = 100;

        @Override
        public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
            super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
            setContentView(R.layout.activity_bluetooth);
            mContext = this;
            Button openButton = (Button) findViewById(R.id.open);
            Button sendButton = (Button) findViewById(R.id.send);
            Button closeButton = (Button) findViewById(R.id.close);
            myLabel = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.label);
            devicesLabel = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.devicelabel);
            devices = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.devices);
            myTextbox = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.entry);
            mBluetoothAdapter = BluetoothAdapter.getDefaultAdapter();

            // Open Button


            openButton.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
                @Override
                public void onClick(View v) {
                    try {
                        openBTConnection();
                    } catch (IOException e) {
                        e.printStackTrace();
                    }
                }
            });
            // Send Button
            sendButton.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
                public void onClick(View v) {
                    try {
                        sendData();
                    } catch (IOException ex) {
                    }
                }
            });

            // Close button
            closeButton.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
                public void onClick(View v) {
                    closeBT();
                }
            });
        }

        private void openBTConnection() throws IOException {
            UUID uuid = UUID.fromString("00001101-0000-1000-8000-00805F9B34FB"); // Standard
                                                                                    // SerialPortService
                                                                                    // ID
            mmSocket = mmDevice.createRfcommSocketToServiceRecord(uuid);
            System.out.println("socket " + mmSocket.toString());
            if (mmSocket != null) {
                mmSocket.connect();
                mmOutputStream = mmSocket.getOutputStream();
                mbuffStream = new BufferedOutputStream(mmOutputStream, 1);
                myLabel.setText("Bluetooth Opened");
            } else {
                myLabel.setText("No bluetooth device found");
            }
        }

        void sendData() throws IOException {
            String msg = myTextbox.getText().toString();
            mbuffStream.write(msg.getBytes(), 0, msg.getBytes().length);
            mbuffStream.flush();
            myLabel.setText("Data Sent");
        }

        void closeBT() {
            try {
                if (mmOutputStream != null) {
                    mmOutputStream.close();
                }
                if (mbuffStream != null) {
                    mbuffStream.close();
                }
                if (mmSocket != null) {
                    mmSocket.close();
                }
            } catch (IOException e) {
                // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
            myLabel.setText("Bluetooth Closed");
        }

        @Override
        public void onBackPressed() {
            closeBT();
            finish();
        }
    }
```

thanks 
Shriram M

Comment: You are doing IO in the main thread. But other than this, I think it should work. I'd start debugging the send button handler, and also logging the received data in the host.

Comment: Thanks Smith. Any way i am unable to send the data continuously. If i press the sendData button the data is not sending second time. Because of this i used Bufferedoutputstream and reduced the size to 1(sendin only one byte of data).

Comment: Now I read your code again, I've noticed you are using `BufferedOutputStream`. As a test, use the regular underlying (non-buffered) stream instead, to rule out buffering issues.

Comment: The reason why i am using BufferedOutputstream is i can flush the stream. Outputstream class flush method implementation is not there to flush. But when using outputstream i can receive the all the inputs once the buffer is full or close the stream. In buffredoutputstream i can control the buffersize to 1.

Comment: I know you want to use the buffered stream, I'm just suggesting to provisionally use the non-buffered stream and see if it works.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have used non-buffered stream also changed  the same in server side code. it got worked.
Thanks Smith..